# Can a regret be expressed?

Tags: verbs, nouns, word-usage, collocation

I know that *interest, dissatisfaction, condolence, apologies* can all collocate with *express*, but I am not sure if *regret* can. I am thinking about the following sentence in particular:

> I would like to **express my regret** for the incident happened yesterday at my room, which Mark complained to you.

Comment: **regret** noun, plural: *regrets* 1. a feeling of sadness, repentance, or disappointment over something that has happened or been done. *she expressed her regret at Virginia's death* (Google Search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressing regret means you’re sorry, so it is used appropriately in your example (although it should be ‘. . . **in** my room **about** which Mark complained to you.’ You could also say ‘I would like to say how sorry I am for the incident . . .

Comment: Using how sorry looks nice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, regret can be used in that context. I have corrected some of the other grammar in that sentence :)

> I would like to express my regret for the incident that happened
>   yesterday in my room, for which Mark complained to you.

If you are really sorry about what happened in your room, you could use:

> I would like to express my **sincere** regret

Comment: Perhaps replace the "for" in "my regret for the incident" with "concerning" or "regarding".

Comment: @martinf So you meant to write this way "I would like to express my regret for the incident regarding the extreme noises made yesterday in my room"

Comment: @MuthukumarPalaniappan -- "I would like to express my regret _regarding_ the incident that happened yesterday in my room, which Mark complained to you about." (I even made another change, after the comma.)